How to manage Azure AD authentication with private endpoints and WAF in a Spring Boot application?
I have configured Azure AD credentials in my Spring Boot project's application.properties file using the dependency spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory. Here is the configuration:
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id=${TENANT_ID_ENV_VAR}
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-id=${CLIENT_ID_ENV_VAR}
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-secret=${CLIENT_SECRET_ENV_VAR}
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.redirect-uri-template=https://www.custdomain.com/login/oauth2/code/

Application Code:
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Greetings! from Webapp";
    }
}

Current Behavior
In my local environment, the authentication flow works perfectly:

A request to http://localhost:8080/ redirects to http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/azure.
This endpoint redirects the user to the Azure AD login page: https://login.microsoftonline.com/....
After successful login, the user is redirected back to the configured redirect URI.

However, in the production environment:

The application is hosted in Azure App Service (ASP).
Due to security requirements, a private endpoint is enabled on Azure App Service, and the application is exposed via a WAF (Web Application Firewall) server.

WAF URL: https://www.custdomain.com/
Backend App Service URL: https://webapp0101.azurewebsites.net/
When a user makes a request to https://www.custdomain.com/, it is forwarded by the WAF to the backend app at https://webapp0101.azurewebsites.net/.
Due to the authentication configuration on the backend, the application redirects the user to:
https://webapp0101.azurewebsites.net/oauth2/authorization/azure.



Since the backend is now private and not publicly accessible, the user receives a 403 Forbidden error.
Desired Outcome
Is it possible to configure the application to bypass the intermediate step of redirecting to the backend's /oauth2/authorization/azure endpoint and instead redirect the user directly to the Azure AD login page (https://login.microsoftonline.com/...)?
Additional Notes

The redirect URI configured in Azure AD is https://www.custdomain.com/login/oauth2/code/.
The goal is to maintain this architecture while adhering to security best practices with the private endpoint and WAF.

How can I achieve this setup?


Is it possible to configure the application to bypass the intermediate step of redirecting to the backend's /oauth2/authorization/azure endpoint and instead redirect the user directly to the Azure AD login page (https://login.microsoftonline.com/...)?

The authorization code flow should be initiated on the OAuth2 client to:

ensure a session is initiated and the session cookie set on the user agent
set some security parameters (in session and in the authorization request URI). These parameters are then checked when the authorization code is returned to the client.

So, no, you can't skip this call to /oauth2/authorization/${registration-id}.
Following HTTP statuses is important in a REST API. So, returning 401 to Unauthorized requests would be a better default than 302 which means Found and is adapted mostly to server-side rendered apps (Thymeleaf, JSP, ...). Your "smart" frontends should know how to handle unauthorized requests and where to authenticate users.
What I do for single-page and mobile applications is:

expose an endpoint listing the authentication options on the Spring client with oauth2Login. This endpoint returns a list of URIs where an authorization code can be initiated (in your case, that would be a list with only one entry pointing to https://www.custdomain.com/oauth2/authorization/azure)
during startup or before trying to log a user in, frontends query this endpoint to know where to redirect users for login
when a user login is required (a user clicks a login button or a request interceptor processes a 401), the frontend redirects the user agent to the authorization endpoint (directly if there is only one entry or prompts the user to choose one if there are several)

